# PyTorch clip_grad_norm vs clip_grad_norm_, what is the differece when it has underline?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gradient, backpropagation

When coding PyTorch in `torch.nn.utils` I see two functions, `clip_grad_norm` and `clip_grad_norm_`.

I want to know the difference so I went to check the documentation but when I [searched](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/search.html?q=clip_grad_norm&check_keywords=yes&area=default) I only found the `clip_grad_norm_` and not `clip_grad_norm`.

So I'm here to ask if anyone knows the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pytorch uses the trailing underscore convention for in-place operations. So the difference is that the one with an underscore modifies the tensor in place and the other one leaves the original tensor unmodified and returns a new tensor.